# Проектирования базы данных оплаты аккаунта

Tags: mysql, sql

Делаю базу данных подобно сайту биржи фриланса. Пользователь пополняет счет, выбирает нужный тип аккаунта и покупает. Каждый аккаунт действует определенное время (1 месяц, 6 и тд..).

Структура БД:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

*payments* - таблица историй пополнения счёта.

*tariffAcount* - виды аккаунтов их сума и длительность действия.

*payment_account* - покупка аккаунта.

Оцените мою структуру и скажите где лучше хранить дату завершения аккаунта.

Comment: а сами Вы как думаете?

Comment: наверно в users

Comment: Тут, кстати, ответ будет сильно зависеть от того, учебное это задание или реальная разработка. В учебном задании могут придраться к _нормальной форме_ базы данных, например. А в боевой базе зачастую удобнее иметь некоторую избыточность. Так что уточните, пожалуйста, вы реализуете реальный проект или это учебное задание?

Comment: это будет не совсем правильно, т.к. по сути Вам нужно сохранить информацию о дате окончания тарифа, а таблица пользователи хранит информацию о пользователях

Comment: @ Sergey Popov, да реальная разработка.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сделайте отдельную таблицу:

```
account_end

user_id(int) tarif_id(int), pay_acc_id(int) date_start(date) date_end(date)
```

где `user_id` - `id` пользователя, `pay_acc_id` - `payment_account id`,  `tarif_id` - `id` тарифа, `date_start` - дата начала купленного аккаунта(тарифа), `date_end` - дата окончания купленного аккаунта(тарифа)

Comment: А если дата окончания купленного аккаунта(тарифа) не закончилась, и пользователь хочет купить еще раз аккаунт. То тогда брать текущую дату окончания + новая дата ?

Comment: ну аккаунт он один (оплатил получил pro), просто разное время пользования этим аккаунтом.

Comment: @Denis изменили структуру на более оптимальную в связи с новыми подробностями(пользователь может купить новый аккаунт при наличии другого)

Comment: @Denis Вам просто нужно будет добавить запись о новом тарифе, будь то 1 или нет, далее просто сравниваете даты и с учетом результатов сравнения выдаете функционал нужного аккаунта.

Comment: @Alex А чем предложенная вами таблица отличается от `payment_account` в вопросе. 2 даты конечно удобнее для проверок.

Comment: @Alex Если я правильно понял ТС сумма в `payment_account` это не сумма платежа, а сумма списанная по тарифу за включение данного аккаунта, что актуально, потому как в таблице тарифов нет истории изменения тарифов. В остальном она выполняет ту же роль, что ваша таблица. В ней конечно поля странно называются, account_id это ваш tarif_id

Comment: @Mike платежи у пользователя скорее всего фиксируются в payments. в payment_account скорее всего фиксируется дата оплаты заказа. а вот новая таблица aacount_end выполняет немного иную роль, хотя ее структура схожа с payments_account.